# Should up/down voting be disabled on closed questions?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, votes

Not to be confused with [How do votes work on closed questions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1900)

This isn't a question of what the current rules are, but rather a request to consider if it should be this way. Admittedly, I thought of this because an OLD closed question of mine got another downvote. Imagine a toddler being slapped in the hand for something he did 5 months ago. That's kind of the reaction I had. Then, allowing a little logic to seep in, I considered this: If the community considered a question bad enough to close,  shouldn't it no longer be eligible for positive reputation? If it's already closed, hasn't the person who asked the question already been given proper dis-incentive to ask that type of question again?

Comment: There is always the possibility that the question will be edited so that it becomes suitable. If you don't think the question is suitable for the site, you are able to delete it, thus ending the possibility that you will be downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I don't think that the mechanics of closed questions should be changed in this respect. What you're proposing would make closed questions almost identical to [a locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), which serves a different purpose from a closed question. Locked questions are "frozen in time", or a snapshot of when it was locked. A locked post has historical significance and/or a lot of popularity and interesting content, but should otherwise be deleted.

A closed question is salvageable. Some people may still consider a closed question a good one. I've upvoted questions that I've voted to close before. A question that was closed may be more likely to garner downvotes, but I don't think there's enough of a causal relationship to "lock in" the votes of a closed question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With 5 upvotes and no-one commenting to the contrary, it looks like this is the communities opinion on the matter.